# MySQL: Look for substring in the person name field

Tags: mysql, select, search, full-text-search, substring

In a MySQL client registry table, how do I quickly search for a substring in the field name of the person? I'm using:

```
Select nclient, name from client where name like '% allen%'
```

In a table with more than 100,000 records, it takes more than 20 seconds and compromises the database service.

How could I structure tables and indexes for quick search by substring?

---more---

In Amazon RDS:

Query_time: 36.805047 Lock_time: 0.000104 Rows_sent: 30 Rows_examined: 71375

```
select
  ncli, nome, date_format(dt_nasc, '%d-%m-%Y') dt_nasc, sex
from
  cli
where
  cod_clin = 275 and nome like '%ALICE% SA%'
order by
  nome
limit
  0, 1000;

`NCLI` INTEGER(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cod_clin` INTEGER(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`NOME` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,

 KEY `NOME` USING BTREE (`cod_clin`, `NOME`),
```

How could I give this functionality (search by part of a name) to my application more efficiently?

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of the table, including your indexes.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Totally irrelevant. MySQL doesn't provide any kind of index that will help with `%...%` searches.

Comment: A full-text index might help.

Comment: Exactly why I asked for the schema and index defs

Comment: With only 100k rows, no simple search like that should take 20 seconds on a varchar column, unless you're running a coal-fired 8 bit server from the old times. LOL ;-)